# Sphinxsearch order by aggregate value

Tags: php, sql, sorting, group-by, sphinx

I have this query in my sphinx.conf:

```
sql_query  = \
SELECT c.id as cid, s.active AS subscriptionActive, c.icof, c.firma, a.textadr, \
r.textz, cc.value, cc.title, cai.description, cai.vat, cai.name, cai.address, AVG(rev.rating) as companyAverageRating \
FROM companies as c \
LEFT JOIN addresses as a ON c.icof = a.icof \
LEFT JOIN rosformaf r ON c.rosformaf = r.kodzaz \
LEFT JOIN company_contacts as cc ON c.id = cc.company_id \
LEFT JOIN company_add_info as cai ON c.id = cai.company_id \
LEFT JOIN subscriptions as s ON c.id = s.company_id \
LEFT JOIN reviews as rev ON c.id = rev.company_id \
GROUP BY c.id \

sql_attr_float = companyAverageRating
sql_attr_bool = subscriptionActive
```

And as you see, i need to get results of companies with average rating. Later I will sort those companies descending by average rating. But when I run indexer --rotate, It stucks and server is going down. Do you know is this the right way to get aggregate value and sort by it, or I should use another way? And do you know other ways of how can I sort by aggregate value?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In itself your query looks fine.

But its a 'heavy' query, so mysql might use a lot of resources to try to 'run' it.

1. Try using `EXPLAIN` on the query (running it independantly of sphinx) to see if you are missing any vital indexes.
2. You could add `ORDER BY NULL` to the end of the query, which will allow mysql to run it slightly quicker (as it doesnt then need to sort the results) - sphinx doesnt need the results in any particular order.
3. Sphinx has support for running `Ranged Queries` which efficiently break down the 'big' query into lots of little ones. Each separate query is then less likely to overload mysql. 
   http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-sql-query-range
4. If still struggling, could calculate the average ratings via a temporally table. Would recommend trying ranged queries first.